# Debugging UWP apps? (difference between attaching through plmdebug vs windbg UI?)

Tags: debugging, uwp, windbg

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj680085(v=vs.85).aspx

With plmdebug you can use /enabledebug + path of windbg.

For example if you want to debug the "Movies & TV" app, it will automatically attach to video.UI.exe when launching the app.

using this:

```
plmdebug /enabledebug Microsoft.ZuneVideo_3.6.25061.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe"
```

But I was wondering if using plmdebug does something different then simply launching the app and attaching to video.UI.exe manually through the windbg UI? Or are these two just two ways of achieving the exact same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plmdebug` disables the app lifetime model (suspend/resume):

This is [written in the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj680085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **/enableDebug Package [DebuggerCommandLine]** 
> Increments the debug reference count for a package. **The package is exempt from PLM policy**
>   if it has a non-zero debug reference count. Each call to /enableDebug
>   must be paired with a call to /disableDebug. If you specify
>   DebuggerCommandLine, the debugger will attach when any app from the
>   package is launched.

So it does this extra step to make sure the app is not suspended during debugging.